# How to find unhandled promises that only happen on Android?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, redux, promise

I'm developing an app that works just fine in iOS, but when we run it on Android we get warnings like the one I paste here and the execution halts:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Callback was already called.
Error: Callback was already called.
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/3d1448ea-4625-468e-8c56-527626fd00b2:86472:36
    at tryCallOne (blob:http://localhost:8081/3d1448ea-4625-468e-8c56-527626fd00b2:16064:14)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/3d1448ea-4625-468e-8c56-527626fd00b2:16165:17
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/3d1448ea-4625-468e-8c56-527626fd00b2:2892:21
    at _callTimer (blob:http://localhost:8081/3d1448ea-4625-468e-8c56-527626fd00b2:2781:9)
    at _callImmediatesPass (blob:http://localhost:8081/3d1448ea-4625-468e-8c56-527626fd00b2:2817:9)
    at Object.callImmediates (blob:http://localhost:8081/3d1448ea-4625-468e-8c56-527626fd00b2:3036:14)
    at MessageQueue.__callImmediates (blob:http://localhost:8081/3d1448ea-4625-468e-8c56-527626fd00b2:2370:18)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/3d1448ea-4625-468e-8c56-527626fd00b2:2197:18
    at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (blob:http://localhost:8081/3d1448ea-4625-468e-8c56-527626fd00b2:2354:11)
    at MessageQueue.flushedQueue (blob:http://localhost:8081/3d1448ea-4625-468e-8c56-527626fd00b2:2196:14)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (blob:http://localhost:8081/3d1448ea-4625-468e-8c56-527626fd00b2:2165:21)
    at http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.js:70:58
console.warn    @   blob:http://localhos…-527626fd00b2:54586
onUnhandled @   blob:http://localhos…-527626fd00b2:15912
onUnhandled @   blob:http://localhos…-527626fd00b2:16324
(anonymous) @   blob:http://localhos…6-527626fd00b2:2864
_callTimer  @   blob:http://localhos…6-527626fd00b2:2781
callTimers  @   blob:http://localhos…6-527626fd00b2:2988
__callFunction  @   blob:http://localhos…6-527626fd00b2:2392
(anonymous) @   blob:http://localhos…6-527626fd00b2:2162
__guardSafe @   blob:http://localhos…6-527626fd00b2:2354
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue  @   blob:http://localhos…6-527626fd00b2:2161
(anonymous) @   debuggerWorker.js:70
```

The main problem is that as I don't get a line where the error is triggered I can not find where the error is. Also, I am not quite sure what should I fix, as the app works without this warnings in iOS.

I managed to isolate a line causing troubles, but I'm not sure what should I fix:

```
async connectChatEngine(chatEngine) {
      const response = await new Promise(resolve => chatEngine.on('$.ready', (data) => {
        resolve(data);
      }));
      console.log('ChatEngine ready to go!');
      return response;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap `await new Promise()` in a `try{} catch(e){}`:

```
async connectChatEngine(chatEngine) {
  try{
    const response = await new Promise(resolve => chatEngine.on('$.ready', (data) => {
      resolve(data);
    }));
    console.log('ChatEngine ready to go!');
    return response;
  } catch(e){
    //handle failure here

    return false;
  }

},
```

Comment: thanks!

And how can I find out where the other promises are defined?